# Tableau Javascript API HTTPS isn't working

Tags: javascript, api, report, tableau-api

I am trying to embed a report onto my website but getting the following error

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsite.com/blah/blah' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://my-tableau-report-location.com/dashboard'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

But on my JS API call I have the url with 'HTTPS://' ie 'https://my-tableau-report-location.com/dashboard'

Do I need to add an API option to make it HTTPS? What am I missing?

Comment: View the source of the page for any http addresses

Comment: Under HTTPS protocol, you cannot have any external reference to http.
Check either if your https url is redirecting to http (for some weird reason)

Comment: Can you simplify a copy of your page to a thin example that reproduces the problem, and then either post a URL or post the HTML and JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely cause for this problem is that SSL has not been enabled or configured properly on Tableau server.

You will need a valid certificate to do do this. 
It can be configured on your tableau server configuration utility > SSL > External webserver SSL.

Here is a detailed [guide](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_config.htm)

I would recommend to skip configuring 'mutual' SSL as it seems to cause even more headaches.

Comment: Most people don't need mutual SSL, but if you are in an environment where all users have their certificates loaded in the browsers, then it tends to work well - and avoids the need to setup SAML, kerberos or other SSO solutions.