# Configure SSL on Tableau Workbook URL

Tags: ssl, reporting, data-visualization, tableau-api

We are doing POC work on integrating tableau reports with portals web application.

When tried accessing reports through our web application interface, we get an error that the iframe is expecting HTTPS but the link being loaded is HTTP. So how can we configure SSL for tableau workbook url in this scenario?
Our workbook url: http://tableau-dev.uhc.com/t/Sphere/views/CPIMAQRStatusReport/Sheet1?:embed=y&:showShareOptions=true&:display_count=no&:…
We are working on other solution to try where we just open the tab and don't use an iframe.

Next question.
What are the steps to keep in mind like (Permissions, Authentication, Security) when integrating our tableau workbooks reports with web application? I know Tableau Server provides comprehensive and robust solutions for all aspects of security but wanted to get a clear understanding to make sure i get exposed to all challenges during my POC work.

Your response is much appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Tableau online help is a great place to start with info about setting up your Tableau server to use https. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_config.htm.

Comment: I'd also recommend separating out your second question into its own question. That's a pretty broad question and you'll get a better reception asking one question at a time, especially since the questions aren't necessarily related.

Comment: Does it have to be in an iframe? You can embed visualizations inside web pages using the Javascript API. I've had great success embedding visualizations from Tableau Server onto web pages. You might run into fewer issues by avoiding the iframe. This is a good starting point to exploring options: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tableau Javascript API HTTPS isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743355/tableau-javascript-api-https-isnt-working)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

Add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";` into your reverse proxy like nginx

Detail info
[Tableau Server behind SSL-Proxy (nginx)](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-7824)